# formData HttpContext.Current.Request.Params always null when using react

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, fetch, multipartform-data

I am not sure if the problem is from the front end or the back end. I know the backend at least works when using postman, whenever using react `HttpContext.Current.Request.Params` is always null. when I print it in my react app before sending the POST request it says there are values.

here is my Js fetch

```
export async function uploadFile(file, type) {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", file);
  formData.append("fileType", type);
  console.log(...formData); //print the correct stuff

  try {
    const url = `${auth.getApi()}/FileUpload`;
    const resp = await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
      headers: new Headers({
        Authorization: auth.BasicAuth(),
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      }),
    });
    return resp;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return e;
  }
}
```

And the is my c# backend code

```
    public class FileUploadController : ApiController
    {
        private static readonly ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        private const string ALLOWED_CORS_ORIGINS = "*";

        [BasicAuthenticationFilter(true)]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post()
        {

            try
            {
NameValueCollection formData = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params;
string fileType = formData.Get("fileType"); // it says it's null
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileType)) //true
```

Comment: did you try doing just `NameValueCollection formData =  Request.Params` ?

Comment: Did you also try using indexer:  `Request["fileType"]`?

Comment: @Chetan NameValueCollection formData =  Request.Params => Compiler Error CS1061. Nice pseudo name.

Comment: @SNBS I did and it was also null

Comment: I'd also try using `Request.Form["fileType"]`.